# High powers of complex numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I have these two questions that I am trying to solve. I know that I am suppose to use De Movire's Theorem but I am getting stuck. Can you guys please help out? Thanks.

> Compute the following powers and give your answer in the form $a+bi$.  Use the square root symbol $\sqrt{}$ where needed to give an exact value for your answer.  You may leave powers of real numbers in exponent form, e.g. $2^{11}$. $$\begin{align}&a)\quad \left(\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}+\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}i\right)^{95} \\ &b) \quad\left(-\sqrt{3}-i\right)^{13}\end{align}$$

Comment: What is (1/rt(2)+i1/rt (2))^2?  Then what is *that* squared?  And *that* squared?

Comment: Note that $\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})=\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.  What do you know about $\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$ in relation to the unit circle?  What do you know about roots of unity?  If not much, then look at $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i)^n$ for $n$ a multiple of four or eight.

Comment: @fleablood yes it is

Comment: Polar form tends to work a little nicer with powers.

Comment: For the other, what angle do the numbers $-\sqrt{3}$ and $-1$ remind you of?  What about $2(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$ and $2(-\frac{1}{2})$?

Comment: @Bye_World I am trying to get the polar form but getting stuck

Comment: To use de moivre theorem, convert to r,theta.  Raise r to the power.  Multiply theta by the power.  Convert back to a+bi.

Comment: @user3504306 JMoravitz seems to be trying to help you with that.

Comment: @Bye_World yeah I am trying to figure out how he got there

Comment: @JMoravitz do you mind explaining your steps a bit more?

Comment: Although I am not a fan of telling people to "memorize" things, one should be familiar with special values of [the unit circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle).  Namely the values for $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$ for $\theta\in\{0,\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{\pi}{2}\}$.  Recognize that the one reminds you of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and the other reminds you of $\frac{\pi}{3}$ or $\frac{\pi}{6}$.  Account for which quadrant it is in based on the signs and which angle it will be to recognize which value of $\theta$ yields that.  Scale by a factor of $r$ if necessary.

Comment: 1/rt2 + i 1/rt2 squared is i.  i^4 = 1.  So 1/rt2 + i/rt2 to the 8th is 1.  So it to the 8th is one.  So it to the 95 is it to the 7th which is i to third times it.  But in polar it is e^ipi/4.  So to the 95 is e^i18 3/4 pi= -1/rt (2) + i 1/rt (2).  For b) that is 2e^150i so to the 13th is ...

Comment: @JMoravitz cool so I got (sqrt(2)^13(cos(5pi/6)+isin(pi/4)) I don't know where to go from here.... This is for the second one

Comment: You know that you are suppose to use De Moivre's theorem.  What is De Moivre's theorm?  Can you tell us.  Now, if you apply it correctly, the answer is much easier than it appears.  Here is a hint.  For eacn of those numbers, as you take higher powers, you will find a cycle that repeats.  So, the full cycles don't matter.  All that you care about will be the remainder.

Comment: @DougM see I kind of know what it does but I am having a hard time applying it

Answer (score 1):

**Big hint:**

$\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

$\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

$\cos(\frac{7\pi}{6})=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

$\sin(\frac{7\pi}{6})=-\frac{1}{2}$

---

$r(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)) = re^{i\theta}$

$e^{2\pi i}=1$

---

> So for the second one, we have:  $(-\sqrt{3}-i)=2(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i)=2(\cos(\frac{7\pi}{6})+i\sin(\frac{7\pi}{6}))$.  Now, raising that to a power...

---

Example worked out:

$(-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}i)^{32}$

We first convert to polar form by recognizing what angle gives us values like those above:

$(-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}i)^{32} = (\frac{1}{2}(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i))^{32} = (\frac{1}{2}(\cos(\frac{2\pi}{3})+i\sin(\frac{2\pi}{3})))^{32}$

$=(\frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}})^{32}$

Apply properties of exponents:  $(a^{b})^c = a^{bc}$

$=(\frac{1}{2})^{32}e^{\frac{64\pi i}{3}}$

Simplify by factoring out integer powers of $e^{2\pi i}$

$=\frac{1}{2^{32}}e^{\frac{60\pi i}{3}}\cdot e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}} = \frac{1}{2^{32}}e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}}$

Convert back to rectangular if you so desire.

$=\frac{1}{2^{32}}(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i) = -\frac{1}{2^{33}}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2^{33}}i$

Answer (score 0):

$z = (\frac1{\sqrt 2} + \frac1{\sqrt 2}i)\\
z = \rho(\cos\theta + i \sin \theta)\\
z^{95} = \rho^{95}(\cos\theta + i \sin \theta)^{95}\\
z^{95} = \rho^{95}(\cos 95\theta + i \sin 95\theta) \text{ -- This is De Moivre's Theorem}\\
\cos (\theta + 2\pi) = \cos\theta,\sin (\theta + 2\pi) = \sin\theta$

Find the remainder of $\frac {95\theta}{2\pi}$. That is, $95\theta = k (2\pi) + r$

$z^{95} = \rho^{95}(\cos r + i \sin r)$

$(\frac1{\sqrt 2} + \frac1{\sqrt 2}i)^{95} = (\frac 1{\sqrt2} - \frac 1{\sqrt2}i)$

Now, I left out the calucations, but you have the process.  See, if you can get an answer.  Then try the second one on your own.

b) 
$z= - \sqrt{3} - i\\
\rho = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = \sqrt{3+1} = 2\\
z = 2(-\frac{\sqrt3}{2} - \frac 12 i)\\
z = 2(\cos \frac{4\pi}{3} + i\sin \frac{4\pi}{3}) \text{ -- 240 degrees if you prefer}\\
z^{13} = 2^{13}(\cos \frac{4\pi}{3} + i\sin \frac{4\pi}{3})^{13}$

$z^{12}$ cycles us around to a multiple of $2\pi$

$z^{13} = 2^{13}(-\frac{\sqrt 3}2 - \frac 12 i)\\
(-\sqrt 3 - i)^{13} = 2^{12}(-\sqrt 3 - i)$

Comment: So I started working on the second one, thinking it might be easier but this is how far I got http://imgur.com/c4KrhTf. I am having a hard time going further

Comment: looks like you got off to a bad start.  $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ you have a minus sign in there.  And $\theta$ should be the same $\theta$ for both $\cos \theta$, and $\sin \theta$